# EDT to GMT Conversion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Input: `Fri, 26 Apr 2013 21:56:31 EDT`

```
 NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [df1 setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"];

  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

 NSString *startDateStr2 = [df1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

 NSLog(@"currentDate: %@", startDateStr2);
```

but i am getting **output :** `Sat, 05 Jan 2013 07:26:31 GMT+05:30`

Answer (score 2):

Use below method which is used to change the format of the `NSDate`..

```
-(NSString *)changeDateFormat:(NSString*)stringDate dateFormat:(NSString*)dateFormat getwithFormat:(NSString *)getwithFormat{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:getwithFormat];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
    return convertedString;
}
```

Call above method with its 3 parameters..

**1. stringDate :** Pass your date which in string type.

**2. dateFormat :** set format which is used in your passed string date. For example, if your string date is `"14-03-2013 11:22 am"` then set the format to `@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"`.

**3. getwithFormat :** Set format which you want, as if you want date `14/03/2013` then just set format `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

How to call this see below example with method:

```
NSString *strSDate = [self changeDateFormat:@"14-03-2013 11:22 am" dateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a" getwithFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"\n\n Now Date => %@",strSDate);
```

**Output is : Now Date => 14/03/2013**

hope its helpful to you...